# How to access gurobi solution variables by original list elements

Tags: gurobi

If I create a variable based on a python list, how can I access the variables using the original list elements?  For example, the following code creates a variable named new_stf based on the list clinics:

```
clinics, stafcap = multidict({'Clnc_1' : 5, 'Clnc_2' : 7, 'Clnc_3' : 7})
new_stf = m.addVars(clinics, lb=0, vtype=GRB.INTEGER, name="new_stf")
```

After optimizing, these variables have names like new_stf[Clnc_1].
1) How can I access the solution variables using the original list elements (e.g. 'Clnc_1' )?
2) Is there a way to iterate over all the solution vars that are part of the new_stf variable without testing for the name string?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code to get a solution for all variables after optimization.

```
vars = model.getVars()
      for v in vars:
        print(v.X)
```